# Cannot install RCov from Gem

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

```
gem install rcov
```

Error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rcov:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

"C:/Program Files/Ruby191/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
Makefile:154: warning: overriding commands for target `C:/Program'
Makefile:148: warning: ignoring old commands for target `C:/Program'
make: *** No rule to make target `"/C/Program', needed by `callsite.o'.  Stop.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Program Files/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rcov-0.9.8 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Program Files/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rcov-0.9.8/ext/rcovrt/gem_make.out
```

This output is now after installing DevKit - to the root Ruby folder.

Comment: I should add this fails from the command line, and via Netbeans too.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, Gem is trying to compile the software for your OS (Windows, apparently).

If you are using the [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) (rather than the incomplete packages at http://ruby-lang.org), you should add the [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) and you will get tools like make, gcc, etc. that will be able to compile many of the gems natively.

Otherwise, you should be able to use the [Win32 binary version of the Rcov gem](http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?rcov#l2).

---

Sadly, the DevKit can't always compile every gem on Win32. But first, a question: did you follow Step 2 of the DevKit's installation instructions to edit the `fstab` file? If so, then the next best thing to do is email the [RubyInstaller Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller) with details of the compilation problem.

I just tried the [Win32 binary rcovrt.so from the Rcov site](http://eigenclass.org/static/rcov/binary-win32/) on my own Windows box, but it doesn't recognize as a valid Windows image, at least with my Ruby 1.9 installation... so figuring out how to make the DevKit compilation to work may be your best bet.

Comment: Dev kit seemed to work - but I receive a new error now. Updated question to reflect this.

Comment: looks like you now need to move your ruby to somewhere without spaces in the pathname

Comment: Indeed... the `C:/Program Files/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rcov-0.9.8/ext/rcovrt/gem_make.out` file will probably show if make isn't escaping or quoting the file paths correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The gem you're trying to use needs to compile native extensions (code which is compiled per system), and for that, it's using a makefile. Have you tried installing make?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it is using GNU make. One option is to install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and install make (under the devel tree in cygwin setup).